# mitmproxy - gRPC server-side streaming response does not captured?

Tags: grpc, mitmproxy

When I tried to make gRPC request through mitmproxy,
`request` is captured but `response` not captured.

I tried to see what is happening with 'mitmdump --set proxy_debug=true' but
I have no clue.

How can I capture gRPC streaming response?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#streaming

When using http2 streaming, you have to `not read entire response` by mitmproxy option

```
--set stream_large_bodies=1
```